# To get the complete list of active clients inside Xorg

Tags: linux, xorg, xserver

Could someone please point me to a place(PDF) where I can find the detail description about the Xserver(Xorg) e.g DIX Layer, OS Layer etc.

Specifically I am looking for how to get the complete list of all the active clients from inside the Xserver(Xorg). How does Xorg maintain this list? Whenever a new request arrives to Xorg, after accepting the connection where does it put information about that client?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you ask? What do you want to achieve? You might use the `xlsclients` command.

Answer (score 6):

Run `xlsclients`.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xlsclients

Documentation about Xorg internals:

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/doc
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/doc
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/ -> many apps and libraries contain their own documentation

Still, reading the source code is usually the best way, since the documentation about Xserver internals is not updated regularly.

Comment: The `xlsclients` is simply llisting some properties (pieces of random data attached to windows) [set on the top windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486189/308316). It's completely worthless and unreliable.